# Are the extreme points of the following polyhedron all integers?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra, discrete-geometry

Let
\begin{equation}
    S := \left\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}:
        \begin{aligned}
             & 0\leq x_{ij}\leq 1,\ i=1,2,\ldots,m,\ j=1,2,\ldots,n                                    \\
             & \sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} = 1,\ j=1,2,\ldots,n                                             \\
             & a_k\leq\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} \leq b_k,\ k=1,2,\ldots,m,\ a_k,b_k\in\mathbb{N}
        \end{aligned}
    \right\}\neq\emptyset,
\end{equation}
and $E_S:=\{x\in S: x \text{ is an extreme point of } S\}$.
Show that $E_S = S\cap\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$.

I can prove that $E_S \supset S\cap\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$. For any $x\in S\cap\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$, suppose there exist $y,z\in S$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$ such that $x=\alpha y + (1-\alpha)z$, then $y=x=z$ due to $0\leq y,z\leq 1$. Thus, $x$ is an extreme point of $S$, i.e., $x\in E_S$.

However, I cannot prove that $E_S \subset S\cap\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$. Could someone help me?

---

I have an idea for $E_S \subset S\cap\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$. **However, I cannot finish the whole proof since discussing a decimal loop in matrix $x$ seems inevitable. Could someone help me? Thanks.**

Assume that there exists an $x\in E_S$ but $x\notin S\cap\{0,1\}^{m\times n}$.
Denote the indices of the active constraints in $a_k\leq\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} \leq b_k$ by $\mathcal{I}(x)$.
For convenience, assume $x_{11}\in(0,1)$. Then there exists $l\neq 1$ such that $x_{l1}\in(0,1)$.

- If $1\notin\mathcal{I}(x)$, there exists $y,z\in S$
  \begin{equation}
                \begin{cases}
                    y_{11}=x_{11}+\epsilon,\ y_{l1}=x_{l1}-\epsilon \\
                    z_{11}=x_{11}-\epsilon,\ z_{l1}=x_{l1}+\epsilon \\
                    y_{ij} = x_{ij}=z_{ij},\ \text{for other } i,j
                \end{cases}\text{ (Incorrect!)}
            \end{equation}
  such that $x=\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{2}z$, which contradicts the assumption that $x$ is an extreme point of $S$.
- Otherwise, $1\in\mathcal{I}(x)$, there exists $p\neq 1$ such that $x_{1p}\in(0,1)$, and $q\neq 1$ such that $x_{qp}\in(0,1)$.

  - If $l\notin\mathcal{I}(x)$, there exists $y,z\in S$
    \begin{equation}
                            \begin{cases}
                                y_{11}=x_{11}+\epsilon,\ y_{l1}=x_{l1}-\epsilon,\ y_{1p}=x_{1p}-\epsilon,\ y_{qp}=x_{qp}+\epsilon \\
                                z_{11}=x_{11}-\epsilon,\ z_{l1}=x_{l1}+\epsilon,\ z_{1p}=x_{1p}+\epsilon,\ z_{qp}=x_{qp}-\epsilon \\
                                y_{ij} = x_{ij}=z_{ij},\ \text{for other } i,j
                            \end{cases}\text{ (Incorrect!)}
                        \end{equation}
    such that $x=\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{2}z$, which contradicts the assumption that $x$ is an extreme point of $S$.
  - Otherwise, $l\in\mathcal{I}(x)$, there exists $r\neq 1$ such that $x_{lr}\in(0,1)$. Then there exists $y,z\in S$
    \begin{equation}
                            \begin{cases}
                                y_{11}=x_{11}+\epsilon,\ y_{l1}=x_{l1}-\epsilon,\ y_{1p}=x_{1p}-\epsilon,\ y_{lr}=x_{lr}+\epsilon \\
                                z_{11}=x_{11}-\epsilon,\ z_{l1}=x_{l1}+\epsilon,\ z_{1p}=x_{1p}+\epsilon,\ z_{lr}=x_{lr}-\epsilon \\
                                y_{ij} = x_{ij}=z_{ij},\ \text{for other } i,j
                            \end{cases}
                        \end{equation}
    such that $x=\frac{1}{2}y+\frac{1}{2}z$, which contradicts the assumption that $x$ is an extreme point of $S$.

Comment: To avoid closing, show some of your efforts at solving it.

Comment: I don't understand the last condition. We're summing up entries of $x$ but how do we choose the bounds $a_k,b_k$, exactly? Are these determined outside of $S$ somewhere?

Comment: Yes. $a_k,b_k$ can be any suitable integers such that S is not empty.